# Get effective_object_story_id for dynamic placement asset customization ad creative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

My goal is to use Facebook's Graph API to fetch engagement data such as comments, reactions, etc. for a given ad that I am running.

I can do this for non video ads by querying the Graph API for the `effective_object_story_id` associated with the ad_creative ID for my ad. Then I can query the Graph API again for the reactions associated with that `effective_object_story_id`. This works without much issue.

The problem is when I try to do this for video ads which are served using dynamic placement asset optimization. (See https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1044825198987622?id=369787570424415).

The `effective_object_story_id` associated with the video `ad_creative` object appears to be a "shell" story object with no reactions or other engagement. However, if I visit `facebook.com/<effective_object_story_id>&dco_ad_id=<ad_id>` in the browser, I can load the Facebook feed version of the story. If I inspect the HTML element containing the post, I can find several references to a facebook URL of the form `facebook.com/<a_different_object_story_id>`. I can then fetch the engagement data I'm looking for by querying `a_different_object_story_id` with the Graph API.

So my question is, how can I get to `a_different_object_story_id` directly in Graph API starting with `ad_id` (or, `ad_creative_id`, or `effective_object_story_id`). I haven't been able to find anything in the Facebook documentation about this, except for a relatively unhelpful note that you can normally do this using the `dynamic_posts` endpoint *except* for ads served with placement asset customization. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/ads-management#adgroup)

Comment: Can you share the URL you used to get comments and reactions based on effective_object_story_id? I am not able to figure this one out.

Comment: I am getting the following error, "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '178796298983076_427316910797679' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",

Comment: Basically facebook didn't provide a way to retrieve all related post_ids from an Ad id.